# Android: Images uploaded over adb not visible over MediaStorage API

Tags: android, permissions, adb, mediastore

I can see folder and list files in "Pictures" folder, which I created from the app. Using MediaStore API (SDK 31). Yet when I upload folder from my computer over adb/android studio in the same folder, I cannot see it at all over MediaStore API.

All necessary permissions are configured.

Comment: You did not tell that you used an Android 11+ device.

Comment: Modern devices should automatically detect changes in file-system and update MediaStorage database. I am not sure in which Android version this change was implemented. For older devices a reboot or manually forced re-index of the MediaStore database should be sufficient. If you have uploaded a number of files I don't know how long indexing them will take.

Comment: `or manually forced re-index` How to invoke that manually @Robert?

Answer (score 0):

Figured that out: as Media Store is a layer above file system, with an own database, it MUST be refreshed after manual upload. Im my case SO-found solutions did not help, but I found the app in Play Store which does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What is "the app"? If someone else has the same problem and finds your answer this will not be helpful if you don't name the app (best with link to PlayStore).